# OpenApi Genrator Import conflicts with Generated model and the library org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity. 'single-type-import' error

Tags: java, spring, swagger, mustache, openapi-generator

I have a schema named 'ResponseEntity'. The model class gets generated with the same name.
This conflicts with the ResponseEntiy class of Springframework and gives an error

**error: a type with the same simple name is already defined by the single-type-import of ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;**

API File:

```
default ResponseEntity<ResponseEntity> myClass() {
 // code
 return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
}
```

Here, the func return-type ResponseEntity is from `org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity`
whereas the Generic type(one in the <>) ResponseEntity is my model class.

Discarded approaches:

1. I do not want to use importmappings to create an external model and map it to the ResponseEntity model. This will create issues on changing the swagger schema.
2. I cannot add Suffix/Prefix to all the generated models.

Is there a way such that?

1. I can add Suffix/Prefix to only that particular generated model.
2. Any workaround to never let the class 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity' be imported. I will add this in the ResponseEntity method of api.mustache class as a prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you know this answer, but I'm going to say it anyway.  The easiest answer is to rename your schema.  Don't use a name that is going to be used by your framework.  I'm honestly surprised that `ResponseEntity` isn't on the list of [reserved words](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/spring.md#reserved-words) for the `Spring` generator.

If renaming the schema itself is out of the question, consider using the `title` property.  To understand it, let's look at how a generator creates the class name.

The generator creates the name of the class one of three ways:

1. The title.  For example, the below class will be called `ResponseEntity`, regardless of what the file is defined as.  This is useful for in line schemas where you don't want to break out the schemas into their own files.  This will always be used as the name if it is present.

```yaml
type: string
title: ResponseEntity
```

2. If the `title` property is missing, then the generator will check one of the following:

- The file name.  If you are using separate files for your schemas, the file name will be used.  So, a file called `ResponseEntity.yml` will become `ResponseEntity.java`.
- The schema name as defined in the components section of the main `openapi.yml` document.

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    ResponseEntity:
      type: string
```

3. Finally, if the schema is not defined elsewhere, and doesn't have a `title` defined, then the generator will create one using the `operationId`.  For example, the following schema will become `Operation200Response.java`

```yaml
paths:
  /resource:
    get:
      tags:
        - resource
      summary: summary
      description: description
      operationId: operation
      responses:
        '200':
          description:  a ResponseEntity
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                properties:
                  type: string
```

As you can see, the `title` property is the very first thing checked by the generator before anything else.  Since you said "This will create issues on changing the swagger schema", I am assuming that means you have access to the schema and you don't want to change the file name as it would be generated from option 2 above.  This is probably because you don't want to update the `$ref` everywhere else it exists.  Adding a title to the schema itself will allow you to change the name of the generated file without impacting anything else.  It will not break your api or any existing `$ref` you have pointing to it.

If adding a `title` property to your schema is still not an option, than the hard way is to create a [custom generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/customization.md#custom-generator-and-template), because there are no other ways to affect the generated class name.